# Cannot get list of file on an external hard disk

Tags: php, directory

I cannot get a list of files and folder using the following lines:

```
<?php
    $dir    = '/media/me/n4m3-0f-my-h4rd-d1sk';
    $files1 = scandir($dir);
    print_r(error_get_last());
    print_r($files1);

?>
```

I followed the first example here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php and this snippet of code works only if the dir is /tmp

I get the following error:

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => scandir(): (errno 13): Permission denied [file] => /var/www/html/index.php [line] => 8 )
```

Comment: What does this show when you add it just after `files1 = scandir` : `print_r(error_get_last());`

Comment: @DaveS the following: Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => scandir(): (errno 13): Permission denied [file] => /var/www/html/index.php [line] => 8 )

Answer (score 0):

The PHP user does not have read access to the disk.

To see the user PHP is set to, you can add this line:

```
echo exec('whoami`);
```

To fix this, give that user access to the drive.  This might mean giving at least read access to everyone.

Comment: The whoami gives me the following result: `www-data`, is it sufficient a `chmod 777 /path/HD`?

Comment: I'd expect that to work.   You should not need write access if you only want to read

Comment: Unfortunately chmod 777 executed as sudo has no effect. The scandir is still not working